# Share an attribute of Singleton class across all child processes without passing it as a function argument

Tags: python, oop, multiprocessing, singleton, multiprocess

I have a Singleton class and I want to share an attribute of that Singleton class across all processes without passing it through a function argument as a shared variable.

Sample code given below:

```
class Singleton():
   abc = {}
   def __call__():
      abc['key'] = ".com"

class myClass(metaclass=Singleton):
   def capslock(name):
      print name.upper()

if __name__==__main__:
   import multiprocessing as mp
   process1 = mp.Process(target=myClass.capslock, args=("stackoverflow"))

   process1.start()
   process1.join()
```

For the print statement, I need name.upper() + abc['key] but all the child processes will have the Singleton attribute empty.

Comment: The point with Singleton classes is that you can just "insantiate" a "new" object of the class and get required attributes.

Comment: First, the *args* argument to `Process `should be a `tuple` and you have passed a single value (try adding a comma following "stackoverflow'). Second, it should be `if __name__== "__main__":` (`__main__` is not defined and so your program as posted cannot possibly run). Third, your description of what the `print` statement is supposed to print out is not clear; I don't see how your `print` statement could possibly print anything other than **STACKOVERFLOW**. Fourth, shouldn't method `capslock` be decorated with *@staticmethod*? Fifth, this is not how you create a singleton using a metaclass.

Answer (score 1):

I am tempted to issue a close vote on your question since it is not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish (see my posted comment to your question).

But if you are trying to automatically add a class attribute `abc` whenever a singleton is created, it will not work the way you propose with multiprocessing because when the singleton instance is serialized/deserialized from the main process to the child process using `pickle`, this bypasses normal instance creation. Any class attributes that have been defined *in the class definition* will be pickled *as originally defined*, but any class attributes that are subsequently added or modified will not be reflected in the child process.

The following code demonstrates how I would create singleton instances with adding a class attribute. But this also demonstrates that when such an instance is pickled to the new child process, the changed class attribute `x` will have the value as defined when the class was created and class attribute `abc`, which is dynamically added subsequent to class creation, will not exist at all:

```py
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self in self._instances:
            print('Creating singleton:')
            instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            self._instances[self] = instance
            # Add class atribute
            instance.__class__.abc = {"key": "com"}
        return self._instances[self]

class myClass(metaclass=Singleton):
    x = 1 # class attribute

    @staticmethod
    def capslock(name):
        print(f'{name.upper()}, attribute x is {myClass.x}, attribute abc is {getattr(myClass, "abc", "missing")}')


if __name__== "__main__":
    import multiprocessing as mp

    # You need to crate an instance of myClass to get
    # class attribute abc. Here myClass.abc will be missing:
    print(f'attribute x is {myClass.x}, attribute abc is {getattr(myClass, "abc", "missing")}')

    myClass_singleton = myClass()
    # Now myClass.abc will exist:
    myClass.x = 2 # change dynamically
    print(f'attribute x is {myClass.x}, attribute abc is {getattr(myClass, "abc", "missing")}')

    # Verify we are getting singletons:
    myClass_singleton_another = myClass()
    print(myClass_singleton is myClass_singleton_another)

    # The class of the singleton and class attributes x and abc will be printed by
    # method capslock. When called by the main process, x will have the modified
    # value of 2 and abc will be a dictionary.
    myClass_singleton.capslock('main process')

    # When capslock is called by the child process, x will again be 1 and
    # abc will be missing entirely:
    process1 = mp.Process(target=myClass_singleton.capslock, args=("child process",))
    process1.start()
    process1.join()
```

Prints:

```None
attribute x is 1, attribute abc is missing
Creating singleton:
attribute x is 2, attribute abc is {'key': 'com'}
True
MAIN PROCESS, attribute x is 2, attribute abc is {'key': 'com'}
CHILD PROCESS, attribute x is 1, attribute abc is missing
```

**A Solution**

Here we customize the `pickle` serialization process to ensure that we also serialize/de-serialize class attribute `abc`. For this we define a mixin class `SingletonMixin` from which our `myClss` class inherits:

```py
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self in self._instances:
            print('Creating singleton:')
            instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            self._instances[self] = instance
            # Add class atribute
            cls = self.__class__
            cls.abc = {"key": "com"}
        return self._instances[self]

class SingletonMixin:
    def __getstate__(self):
        return getattr(myClass, "abc", {}), self.__dict__

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        abc, __dict__ = state
        self.__dict__.update(__dict__)
        self.__class__.abc = abc

class myClass(SingletonMixin, metaclass=Singleton):

    def capslock(self, name):
        print(f'{name.upper()}, attribute abc is {getattr(myClass, "abc", "missing")}')

if __name__== "__main__":
    import multiprocessing as mp

    # You need to crate an instance of myClass to get
    # class attribute abc. Here myClass.abc will be missing:
    print(f'attribute abc is {getattr(myClass, "abc", "missing")}')

    myClass_singleton = myClass()
    # Now myClass.abc will exist:
    myClass.x = 2 # change dynamically
    print(f'attribute abc is {getattr(myClass, "abc", "missing")}')

    # Verify we are getting singletons:
    myClass_singleton_another = myClass()
    print(myClass_singleton is myClass_singleton_another)

    # The class of the singleton and class attributes x and abc will be printed by
    # method capslock. When called by the main process, x will have the modified
    # value of 2 and abc will be a dictionary.
    myClass_singleton.capslock('main process')

    # When capslock is called by the child process, x will again be 1 and
    # abc will be missing entirely:
    process1 = mp.Process(target=myClass_singleton.capslock, args=("child process",))
    process1.start()
    process1.join()
```

Prints:

```None
attribute abc is missing
Creating singleton:
attribute abc is {'key': 'com'}
True
MAIN PROCESS, attribute abc is {'key': 'com'}
CHILD PROCESS, attribute abc is {'key': 'com'}
```